# OpenFL Android builds and filtering armv5/armv6 devices on Google Play

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play, openfl, nme

I am using OpenFL to build an Android app to distribute on Google Play. I want to target only `armv7` devices, and I believe OpenFL does `armv7`-only builds by default.

However when building the OpenFL build system creates and populates the `libs/armeabi` folder instead of a `libs/armeabi-v7a` folder. The problem with this is that this makes Google Play believe that the resulting apk supports `armv5/armv6/armv7` when in reality it only supports `armv7`. This means my apps get some 1-star reviews from people with the older/incompatible devices.

On this [Github issue](https://github.com/openfl/lime-tools/issues/61), Joshua Granick (jgranick) explains why the build tools do this:

> Oh and BTW, originally we tried only armeabi-v7, but it failed to run on certain devices. This is why there's the current behavior or using armeabi, and adding armeabi-v7 only if there is an armv5/6 version too

I would like to know what the issue he mentions is, and what devices/Android versions it would affect. Depending on what it is, it may be possible to still just do an `armv7` build and manually blacklist the buggy devices.

A final option is to simply support the `armv5/armv6` devices by doing a "fat" build, or by only building for `armv5` which I assume is compatible everywhere. This is quite easy using the `<architecture>` tag in the `project.xml` file. It's a tradeoff I may take if there is no way to work around the problem Joshua mentioned.

Also using the Google Play developer dashboard I could also blacklist armv5/armv6 devices manually, but it would be very time consuming to do this for every app/apk.

So my question is: how can I make `armv7`-only Android builds using OpenFL and get Google Play to only allow compatible devices, without running into problems like the one I quoted above? If that isn't possible, then what is my best option?

For reference here are the relevant Google Play apk details I get when I build `armv7`-only:

[image: google play armeabi]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openfl/lime-tools/issues/96). Some armv7 devices or the versions of Android on them cause apps to crash when there is no `libs/armeabi` folder in the apk. Joshua explained how this led to lime-tools (as of `version 1.5.7`) setup:

> in my Samsung Galaxy S (perhaps other devices) the applications would not run unless there was a "libs/armeabi" folder
>
> If there are both folders, it prefers the armeabi-v7a directory, but otherwise failed to work. So that's why the tools use only a single folder if you target only armv7, and use both folders if you include armv5 and armv7 both.
>
> I'm not sure of a good solution for this, I think the key point of friction here is the Google Play submission process, which should allow us to account for that.

Given this, the solution that works for me was to simply do fat builds of my apps and also support armv5/armv6 devices.

Comment: There's an option to have multiple version of applications that will people use depending on the device. I'm not sure if it's applicable in this case though http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html